# Randomly generating invoice IDs - moving text database into script file?

Tags: database, bash, shell, random

I've come up with the following `bash` script to randomly generate invoice numbers, preventing duplications by logging all generated numbers to a text file "database".

To my surprise the script actually works, and it seems robust (although I'd be glad to have any flaws pointed out to me at this early stage rather than later on).

What I'm now wondering is whether it's at all possible to move the "database" of generated numbers into the script file itself. This would allow me to rely on and keep track of just the one file rather than two separate ones.

Is this at all possible, and if so, how? If it isn't a good idea, what valid reasons are there not to do so?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

generate_num() {
#num=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:digit:]' | cut -c 1-5) [Original method, no longer used]
num=$(shuf -i 10000-99999 -n 1)
}

read -p "Are you sure you want to generate a new invoice ID? [Y/n] " -n 1 -r
echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] 
    then
        generate_num && echo Generating a random invoice ID and checking it against the database...
        sleep 2

        while grep -xq "$num" "ID_database"
            do
                echo Invoice ID \#$num already exists in the database...
                sleep 2
                generate_num && echo Generating new random invoice ID and checking against database...
                sleep 2
            done

        while [[ ${#num} -gt 5 ]]
            do
                echo Invoice ID \#$num is more than 5 digits...
                sleep 2
                generate_num && echo Generating new random invoice ID and checking against database...
                sleep 2
          done

        echo Generated random invoice ID \#$num
        sleep 1
        echo Invoice ID \#$num does not exist in database...
        sleep 2
        echo $num >> "ID_database" && echo Successfully added Invoice ID \#$num to the database.

    else 
        echo "Exiting..."
    fi
```

Comment: Tip: [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: @BasilBourque I selected a 5-digit ID because I need it to look pretty/memorable for the clients and fit on my invoice, and because it's a very small localised business that won't ever come close to going through the whole keyspace of 100,000 numbers. The current logic checks twice against duplicates, so collisions are a non-issue and I'm no longer thinking about the length of the ID. If you can see a flaw in that logic or elsewhere in the code I'd be glad to have it pointed out, but I'm mainly interested in the question I asked.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description).

Comment: What about a counter that starts at 1 and increases by 1 for every invoice you send out? Why make it random? You could put the date in it to make it easier when doing the books. `YYYYMMDD-SequenceNr`. It sorts nicely too.

Comment: @Cyrus I'm already getting my desired output. Please read the body of the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I settled on a random ID to ensure that even with a small amount of jobs clients can't easily predict how much business there's been. As I said above, a lot of thought has gone into the format of the ID and works fine for my needs as is. The question I'm trying to get answered is separate.

Comment: @Prometheus Sure, but what looks random doesn't necessarily have to _be_ random. You could keep a counter in a file and hash it for example. Perhaps overkill. You could however keep a file database of all the numbers htat's been taken. Just `touch dbdir/$invno` when a number is taken. You can then test if it is taken with `if [[ -e dbdir/$invno ]]`. No need to keep that inside the script. Use the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend this because:

- These things are fragile. One bad edit and your invoice database is corrupt.
- It makes version control a pain. Each new version of the script should preferably be checked in. You could add logic to make sure that `"$mydir"` is an empty directory when you run the script (except for `"$myname"`, `.git` and other [git](/questions/tagged/git)-related files) then run `git -C "$mydir" init` if `"$mydir"/.git` doesn't exist. Then for each database update, `git -C "$mydir" add "$myname"` and `git -C "$mydir" commit -m "$num"`. It's just an idea to explore...
- Locking - It's possible to do file locking to make sure that not two users run the script at the same time, but it adds to the complexity so I didn't bother. If you feel that's a risk, you need to add that.

... but you want a self-modifying script, so here goes.

This just adds a new invoice number to its internal database for each time you run it. I've explained what goes on as comments. The last line should read `__INVOICES__` (+ a newline) if you copy the script.

As always when dealing with things like this, remember to make a backup before making changes :-)

As it's currently written, you can only add *one* invoice per run. It shouldn't be hard to move things around (you need a new tempfile) to get it to add more than one if you need that.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e    # exit on error - imporant for this type of script
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myname="$0"
mydir=$(dirname "$myname")

if [[ ! -w $myname ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: You don't have permission to update $myname" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# create a tempfile to be able to update the database in the file later
#
# set -e makes the script end if this fails:
temp=$(mktemp -p "$mydir")
trap "{ rm -f "$temp"; }" EXIT # remove the tempfile if we die for some reason

# read current database from the file
readarray -t ID_database <<< $(sed '0,/^__INVOICES__$/d' "$0")
#declare -p ID_database >&2    # debug
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# a function to check if a number is already in the db
is_it_taken() {
    local num=$1
    # return 1 (true, yes it's taken) if the regex found a match
    [[ ! " ${ID_database[@]} " =~ " ${num} " ]]
}

generate_num() {
    local num
    (exit 1) # set $? to 1

    # loop until $? becomes 0
    while (( $? )); do
        num=$(shuf -i 10000-99999 -n 1)
        is_it_taken "$num"
    done

    # we found a free number
    echo $num
}

add_to_db() {
    local num=$1

    # add to db in memory
    ID_database+=($num)

    # add to db in file:

    # copy the script to the tempfile
    cp -pf "$myname" "$temp"

    # add the new number
    echo $num >> "$temp"

    # move the tempfile into place
    mv "$temp" "$myname"
}
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

num=$(generate_num)

add_to_db $num

# your business logic goes here:

echo "All current invoices:"
for invoice in ${ID_database[@]}
do
    echo ">$invoice<"
done

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# leave the rest untouched:
exit
__INVOICES__
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and I'll test fully soon, but part of the question was also for what reasons self-modifying scripts aren't recommended.

Comment: @Prometheus I added the first things that popped up. I think I can keep on adding :-)

Comment: Appreciated. Most of these issues seem to apply to scaling but as things stand, I see no risks from running this so long as the invoices are always appended to the bottom of the script file. Also if you could upvote the question I would appreciate it, someone seems to think it was a bad question and neglected to explain why.

Comment: @Prometheus Yeah, I thought it was interesting enough to spend some time on it, even though I think it's a bad idea :-), so you got my upvote. The risk is mainly in the hands of the user. One tired day when you want to update the script, you slip up - and boom.  :-) The `git` idea for version control may be one way to add safety. You can then always revert back to the previous version if something happens.

Comment: Just tested, and the script only returns one invoice number if the last line is the INVOICES header. It needs the last line to be a newline in order to work as intended, which I just added manually.

Comment: @Prometheus I actually wrote "The last line should read `__INVOICES__` (+ a newline)" but scrapped that last part before posting it :-) I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

### Edited

To answer the question you *asked* -

Make sure your file ends with an explicit `exit` statement.
Without some sort of branching it won't execute past that, so unless there is a gross parsing error anything below *could* be used as storage space. Just

```
echo $num >> $0
```

If you write your records directly onto the bottom of the script, the script grows, but ...relatively harmlessly. Just make sure your `grep` pattern doesn't grab any lines of code, though `grep -E '^\d[%]$'` seems pretty safe.

---

This is only ever going to give you a max of ~90k id's, and spends unneeded time and cycles on redundancy checking. Is there a limit on the length of the value?

If you can assure there won't be more than one invoice processed per second,

```
date +%s >> "ID_database" # the UNIX epoch, seconds since 00:00:00 01/01/1970
```

If you need more precision that that,

```
date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N
```

will output Year month day hour minute second nanoseconds, which is both immediate and "pretty safe".

```
date +%s%N # epoch with nanoseconds
```

is shorter, but doesn't have the convenient side effect of automatically giving you the date and time of invoice creation.

If you absolutely need to guarantee uniqueness and nanoseconds isn't good enough, use a lock of some sort, and maybe a more fine-grained language.

On the other hand, if minutes are unique *enough*, you could use

```
 date +%y%m%d%H%M
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Sorry, yes, 90K numbers, but this is still more than enough for my needs. I'm unsure what "unneeded time and cycles" you're referring to, but as already explained above, the random 5-digit format of the ID has already been decided on after a lot of calculations and thinking. This is not an answer to the actual question I asked.

Comment: As you liike. Edited.